# Syntax error on DB2 XMLELEMENT

Tags: db2, sqlxml, ibm-data-studio

I get this error when trying out this command in the BIRT Classic Models sample database in Data Studio

```
select xmlelement(name "custno", customers.customernumber) from customers
```

> Syntax error: Encountered "\"custno\"" at line 1, column 24.

I do not know how to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: No it is not solved and I do need further help.

Comment: SOLVED: Database server was at a version that predates XML functionality so no XML function would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `db2`, but according to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022188.html) your statement looks quite alrigth (although I'd place an alias to name this field...)

But this

> Syntax error: Encountered "\"custno\"" at line 1, column 24.

seems to be a quite clear hint, that your error is connected to the `NAME` of the element.

I'm pretty sure, that this statement was created on string level.
Did you try to escape the `"`-characters with `\"`?
The SQL reaching the engine might look like

```
select xmlelement(name \"custno\", customers.customernumber) from customers
or
select xmlelement(name "\"custno"\", customers.customernumber) from customers
```

... which is wrong of course...

But to be honest: just guessing...